# How can I draw a continuous line using d3 without needing to click&drag the mouse, but rather just use the mouseover event?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dom-events

I am trying to use d3 to draw a continuous line without clicking the mouse. Currently I have this d3 code that works when I click and move, but does not work when I simply enter the area where the line should be drawn. I provided a CodePen link here: https://codepen.io/pwill2/pen/NLdJoL

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Freehand drawing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg id="canvas" width="500px" height="250px"></svg>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.css

```
#canvas {
  background: oldlace;
}
.swatch {
  pointer-events: all;
}
.swatch.active {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: black;
}
.swatch {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn {
  pointer-events: all;

  font-family: FontAwesome;
  fill: #333;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-anchor: middle;

  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.btn:hover {
  fill: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

index.js

```
(function() {
  var SWATCH_D, active_color, active_line, canvas, drag, drawing_data, lines_layer, palette, redraw, render_line, swatches, trash_btn, ui;

  SWATCH_D = 22;

  render_line = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
    return d[0];
  }).y(function(d) {
    return d[1];
  }).interpolate('basis');

  drawing_data = {
    lines: [
      {
        color: "#000000",
        points: []}
    ]
  };

  active_line = null;

  active_color = "#000000";

  canvas = d3.select('#canvas');

  lines_layer = canvas.append('g');

  drag = d3.behavior.drag();

  drag.on('dragstart', function() {
    active_line = {
      points: [],
      color: active_color
    };
    drawing_data.lines.push(active_line);
    return redraw(active_line);
  });

  drag.on('drag', function() {
    active_line.points.push(d3.mouse(this));
    return redraw(active_line);
  });

  drag.on('dragend', function() {
    if (active_line.points.length === 0) {
      drawing_data.lines.pop();
    }
    active_line = null;
    return console.log(drawing_data);
  });

  canvas.call(drag);

  redraw = function(specific_line) {
    var lines;
    lines = lines_layer.selectAll('.line').data(drawing_data.lines);
    lines.enter().append('path').attr({
      "class": 'line',
      stroke: function(d) {
        return d.color;
      }
    }).each(function(d) {
      return d.elem = d3.select(this);
    });
    if (specific_line != null) {
      specific_line.elem.attr({
        d: function(d) {
          return render_line(d.points);
        }
      });
    } else {
      lines.attr({
        d: function(d) {
          return render_line(d.points);
        }
      });
    }
    return lines.exit().remove();
  };

  redraw();

}).call(this);
```

Comment: You're trying to draw without mousedown correct (whenever the mouse is over the canvas)? Why not `canvas.on("mousemove", ...`, ([eg](https://jsfiddle.net/epgtruyL/)), or am I missing something?

Comment: Your solution works great! I would really love to keep the line looking as smooth as it does in the CodePen example. Do you know if there is any way to ensure that?

Comment: Interpolation of the lines into smoother shapes is difficult: with a point for each mousemove you have too many points too close together to do much with it. By removing some and resampling along an interpolated curve you might get nice results, but you'd want to consider how far each point is from the next to determine sampling points rather than using index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a drag, why not listen for a `mousemove` event on your canvas and push points to a path drawing function that way.

As a simple example:

```js
var points = [];
var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("canvas")
   .attr("height",500)
   .attr("width", 600)
   .on("mousemove", addPoint);
      
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
      
function addPoint() {
   points.push(d3.mouse(this));
   draw();
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(...points[0]);
  points.forEach(function(d) {
    context.lineTo(...d);
  })
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to have drawing after a click on each entry of the mouse over the canvas, you could assign the mousemove listener on click too (mouse out removes the mousemove listener below, so you can draw multiple lines):

```js
var points = [];

var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("canvas")
   .attr("height",500)
   .attr("width", 600)
   .on("click", function() {
     points.push([])
     d3.select(this).on("mousemove", addPoint);
   })
   .on("mouseout", function() {
     d3.select(this).on("mousemove",null);
   })
   
      
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
      
function addPoint() {
   points[points.length-1].push(d3.mouse(this));
   draw();
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
  points.forEach(function(p) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(...p[0]);
    p.forEach(function(d) {
      context.lineTo(...d);
    })
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And if you wanted to smoothen out the curves because hands are shaky you could use d3.line and a d3 curve to draw the lines:

```js
var points = [];
var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("canvas")
   .attr("height",500)
   .attr("width", 600)
   .on("mousemove", addPoint);
      
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

var line = d3.line().context(context)
    .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);
      
function addPoint() {
   points.push(d3.mouse(this));
   draw();
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0,0,600,600)
  context.beginPath();
  line(points);  
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Though you could also filter out points in the array to get something smoother (since points added by mousemove will be added very close together depending on mouse speed, making smoothening harder), or use different d3 curves:

```js
var points = [];
var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("canvas")
   .attr("height",500)
   .attr("width", 600)
   .on("mousemove", addPoint);
      
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

var line = d3.line().context(context)
    .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);
      
function addPoint() {
   points.push(d3.mouse(this));
   draw();
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0,0,600,600)
  context.beginPath();
  line(points.filter(function(p,i) {
    if(i%8 == 0 || i == points.length-1) return p;
  }));  
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your solution works great! I would really love to keep the line looking as smooth as it does in the CodePen example. Do you know if there is any way to ensure that?

Comment: @ParkerWilliams, have updated for a bit more on events and smoothening

Comment: there is an extra `curve` variable. Nice final example. Why not put the `%8` in the add routine, `pop` last one if not `%8` and add new one?

Comment: @rioV8, thanks for the sharp eyes - I wasn't paying that much attention apparently, fixed now. I didn't give too much thought on the sampling method, it was just for demonstration, I do think a proper sampling method would consider distance between points to some degree if not entirely.

Comment: @AndrewReid, So this is working great. Only question I have now. If I want to get this to work on a styled html page, for example, a form, I no longer have the ability to interact with the form (buttons, drop-downs, text input fields). Any idea on how to get that to work? Thanks!